# How can I stop Konsole from converting hard tabs to spaces?

Tags: konsole

Open Konsole, and try a command like this one:

```
$ echo -e 'a\tb\tc'
a   b   c
```

Now copy and paste the result into a spreadsheet application like LibreOffice Calc, or Google Sheets. If you had used GNOME Terminal, this would put each word in a separate cell, because the application recognises the hard tabs.

However, Konsole converts the hard tabs to spaces, and therefore when you copy and paste the text into a spreadsheet application, the three words take up one cell.

How do you fix Konsole to make it preserve hard tabs?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's konsole that is converting tabs to spaces. What happens if you run the command and output to a text file by adding `> output.txt` to the end of the command?

Comment: I also have a vague recollection about something something difficult to [implement](https://superuser.com/a/826347/1105628)

Comment: @Nmath When running `echo -e 'a\tb\tc' > output.txt`, the hard tabs are preserved in the text file.